# Error: Couldn't find package "@wow/common@1.0.0" required by "react-native-web-workout-series@0.1.0" on the "npm" registry

Tags: react-native, npm, command-line-interface, yarnpkg

I have problems running my web app using this tutorial video [React Native Web Full App Tutorial - Build a Workout App for iOS, Android, and Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CBYbEGvxYY)
 in react-native. I've been searching a lot for an answer but there is no accurate one yet that solves my issue.

I downloaded the app from here: [git repo](https://github.com/benawad/react-native-web-series).

```
error Couldn't find package "@wow/common@1.0.0" required by "@wow/app@0.0.1" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Couldn't find package "@wow/common@1.0.0" required by "react-native-web-workout-series@0.1.0" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: it would help ppl understand and answer your question if you could provide a reproducible row of your json string with required output. The images are not clear.

Comment: What exact command are you running to get that error and from what directory? It appears that the failing packages are part of the yarn workspace, and things are working properly in my local test.